# Transition Duration Does not work in React-Apps?

Tags: css, reactjs

Im new in react-apps and im creating a simple form which has only an input and a button,i add styles to button but the transition duration doesnt work,how can i fix this in react ? without react it will work but in react i have this problem . this is my style for button

```
.form{
    width: 700px;
}
.btn-detect{
        background-color: #000;
        color: #fff;
        border: none;
        font-family: 'Felix Titling';
        letter-spacing: 2px;
        left: 0;
        -webkit-transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
        transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;

    }
    .btn-detect:hover{
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
        -moz-transform: scale(1.5);
        -o-transform: scale(1.5);
        -ms-transform: scale(1.5);
        transform: scale(1.5);
    }
```

this is react-component :

```
const ImageLinkForm = () => {
    return(
        <div>
            <p className='f3 pt'>
                {'This Magic Brain will detect faces in your pictures,Give it a try!'}
            </p>
            <div className='center'>
                <div className='form center pa4 br3 shadow-5'>
                <input className='f4 pa2 w-70 center' type='text' />
                <button className='btn-detect w-30 f5 link pointer'>Detect</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is good, probably you set the styles in the wrong component/file and due to style encapsulation it doesn't take affect or the css class name is misspelled.

If you need more assistance please provide the react component code.

Comment: i added react component,i really dont know whats wrong with this

Answer (score 0):

I made a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/n0x8jwm180) to test your code, and the animation is working. I am not really sure, but can you try changing the single-quote (`'`) in your code to double-quotes (`"`)? JSX attributes should be using double-quotes.

Update:
Can you show your folder and file structure and show how you import the css file?

Comment: i tried double-quotes but nothing has changed,here is my file structure [link](https://pasteboard.co/HuG8wRP.png)

Comment: Are all the css not working? Or just the animation part?

Comment: its just the animation part,other properties are working fine

Comment: Can you provide the browser and the version of it that you are using?

Comment: im using Chrome (Version 67.0.3396.99)... i tried more and it seems like all the transitions are working except for this button,maybe there is a something wrong with the syntax

Comment: i made it,it had problem with one of tachyons's classes,thanks for your time,i appreciate it :)